# How to filter one PBI table off of another

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables on a PBI Dashboard, one that shows Date, Airline Code, Flight Number and Passengers per Flight, and then a table that shows information such as passenger name, date, reservation ID etc.

The first table is filtered to only show flights that have 5 or more people on a flight. Which works fine. I am trying to find a way to filter the second table based on the values that are left in the first table. So the second table should only show the individual traveler records who are on flights with 5+ people. I can't apply a filter with Passenger per Flight, as once I have the traveler information included, it will always be = 1.

Essentially, I want to add a measure into the second table on the right that will NOT take into account the identifiers such as passenger name and reservation ID. It should show the same count for each flight as what's shown on the first table on the left.

I'm sure it's a simple solution, but haven't been able to come to it.

```
Passenger per Flight = CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact Reservation'[TravellerID]),
 'Dim TravelType'[Travel Type] = "Air"
    
)
```

[image]

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships) between the two tables that is configured to flow filters from the flight table to the passenger details table.